# Arduino: int32_t from two's complement

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion, 32-bit

I'm trying to achieve a simple thing: read 4 bytes of data from ADC via SPI and combine them into signed (int32_t) value, but I'm getting unexpected results (see plot). My function for reading the ADC is as follows:

```
int32_t readDataContinuous() {
  //  delayMicroseconds(100);
  while (digitalRead(DRDYPin) == HIGH) {
    //do nothing (waiting for the conversion to finish)
  }
  int32_t resp;
  digitalWrite(CSPin, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(40000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
  resp = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  resp <<= 8;
  resp |= SPI.transfer(0x00);
  resp <<= 8;
  resp |= SPI.transfer(0x00);
  resp <<= 8;
  resp |= SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CSPin, HIGH);
  SerialBT.println(resp);
  return resp;
}
```

[image: see plot]

Any ideas?

Comment: When signal is supposed to go below zero the function 'flips' showing very high values instead of going below zero.

Comment: Are you sure you're treating the values as signed integers when you plot them?

Comment: What you see is completely normal for two's complement, however you have it backwards.  You are misinterpreting the most significant bit as sign, so that when the function is supposed to go to high values, you are misinterpreting them as negative values instead.  Change to `uint32_t`.

Comment: It would be nice to know what is the scale of this chart. Please provide values for strategic points of this chart. Depending on that it may turn out that you assumed big endian and data are in little endian or data printed in chart are misinterpret.

Comment: CTO, What is the return type of `SPI.transfer()`?

Comment: Could be your ADC gives unsigned values with zero being the most negative input it can read, in which case your signed values need to be lowered by whatever value represents a zero input level.  Or if the ADC gives you signed values with the offset already applied, maybe you're just plotting the signed values as if they were unsigned.

Comment: Sorry for cropping the scale. It's only positive values ranging from 0 to 2.1e9 (i.e. 2,147,483,647).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering! The cause of this behavior was partially hardware-related. After lowering the SPI bus frequency the problem has gone. The uC was unable to determine the first (sign) bit of an SPI transaction properly. Therefore I was getting only positive values.
[ok now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/839nN.png)